# HMACSHA256 on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: cryptography, windows-phone-8.1

According to this MSDN article, there exists a class for generating HMACSHA256 hash codes in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace on WP8. However, the .Cryptography namespace doesn't appear to exist. Is something wrong with my project or is this documentation wrong? Is there another way to compute HMACSHA256 hashes on WP8?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: If you find no built-in way, there's a free CryptoBlackbox package in our SecureBlackbox product which will let you do this. https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cryptobb.php

Comment: The MSDN page that you referenced contains "Supported in: 8.1, 8.0, 7.1, 7.0". Did you include/import all the relevant libraries in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much anguish, I have a function that works.

```
public static string HmacSha256(string secretKey, string value)
{
    // Move strings to buffers.
    var key = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(secretKey, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    var msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(value, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

    // Create HMAC.
    var objMacProv = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
    var hash = objMacProv.CreateHash(key);
    hash.Append(msg);
    return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hash.GetValueAndReset());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Windows Phone 8.1 app: those that are based on Silverlight (like with WP7.X & WP8.0) and those based on the Universal/RT/Jupiter format (as also used by Windows 8.1).

The `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace is only available for Silverlight apps and is not available if using the newer/other format.

Yes, it's unfortunate that the documentation doesn't make this clear.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using a Silverlight style app.  So, are there no crypto functions in the "new" app style?  Can it really be missing such basic functions necessary for connecting with web APIs?

Comment: @IanLee welcome to the wonderful world of "universal apps" everything is different. Try the `Windows.Security.Cryptography` and `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core` namespaces instead. YOu should still be able to get the same hashes but with different classes/methods.